# HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9 - server to server connetion

Tags: networking, hp, hp-proliant

Just want to know if I can do a server to server connection via Cat6 cable for:
HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? What have you done so far? On the face, this seems like an odd question... it's definitely possible, though.

Answer (score 3):

> Just want to know if I can do a server to server connection via Cat6
>   cable for: HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9

Yes.

Comment: and the NIC's support  Auto-MDIX  so you don't even need a cross-over cable